# Как разместить надписи под иконками по центру иконок

Tags: android

Необходимо сделать разметку на главном экране приложения в виде 6 иконок.
Будет 2 ряда по 3 иконки, а под каждой из них - надпись.
Сделал 2 `LinearLayout` и отцентрировал их, но никак не могу сделать надписи так, чтобы они на экране всех Android-устройств выглядели ровно по центру иконки.

Подскажите, как мне лучше сделать?

**Разметка**:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:onClick="gotoNewActivityStart"
        android:background="@drawable/ico1"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton5"
        android:background="@drawable/ico2"
        android:onClick="gotoNewActivityLex"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton6"
        android:background="@drawable/map"
        android:onClick="gotoNewActivityMap" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @pavlofff, а как же мне тогда лучше поступить, чтобы все было выполнено красиво?

Comment: Используйте `TableLayout` с ячейками 3х4 - В рядах располагайте попеременно картинки и текст, внутри ячейки центрируйте с помощью `gravity`

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все просто - нужно поместить `ImageButton` и `TextView` просто в один вертикальный `LinearLayout` и все. И еще я заметил, что поскольку вы задаете свойство `android:background`, то нет никакого смысла использовать `ImageButton`, поэтому я заменил их просто на `Button`. `ImageButton` используются с атрибутом `android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"`

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:onClick="gotoNewActivityStart" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@android:string/ok" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"           
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/imageButton5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:onClick="gotoNewActivityLex" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@android:string/ok" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"              
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/imageButton6"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:onClick="gotoNewActivityMap" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@android:string/ok" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @Evgeny_Karavashkin, Вы очень помогли! Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Итак у вас 2 ряда по 3 иконки.

Я бы сделал один LinearLayout, горизонтальный, в который весом разбить на 3 части.

В каждой части LinearLayout вертикальный, с gravity = center_horizontal, и в котором идет картинка, подпись, картинка, подпись.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант в `LinearLayout` размещать не три `ImageButton`, а три отцентрованных  `LinearLayout` с картинкой и подписью